# wait child process but get error: 'pid is not a child of this shell'

Tags: linux, shell, wait

I write a script to get data from HDFS parallel, then I wait these child processes in a for loop, but sometimes it returns `pid is not a child of this shell`. sometimes, it works well. It's so puzzled. I use `jobs -l` to show all the jobs run in the background. I am sure these pid is the child process of the shell process, and I use `ps aux` to make sure these pids is note assign to other process. Here is my script.

```
PID=()
FILE=()
let serial=0

while read index_tar
do
        echo $index_tar | grep index > /dev/null 2>&1

        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
        then
                continue
        fi

        suffix=`printf '%03d' $serial`
        mkdir input/output_$suffix
        $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -cat $index_tar | tar zxf - -C input/output_$suffix \
                && mv input/output_$suffix/index_* input/output_$suffix/index &

        PID[$serial]=$!
        FILE[$serial]=$index_tar

        let serial++

done < file.list

for((i=0;i<$serial;i++))
do
        wait ${PID[$i]}

        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
        then
                LOG "get ${FILE[$i]} failed, PID:${PID[$i]}"
                exit -1
        else
                LOG "get ${FILE[$i]} success, PID:${PID[$i]}"
        fi
done
```

Comment: A good question, I am getting exactly the same error. I launched 96 background jobs and waited for them. 4 of the 96 gave me the "pid 28991 (this number is the random child PID as an example) is not a child of this shell". I assume that the wait command is not foolproof. I will do some digging.

Answer (score 31):

Just find the process id of the process you want to wait for and replace that with 12345 in below script.  Further changes can be made as per your requirement.

```
#!/bin/sh
PID=12345
while [ -e /proc/$PID ]
do
    echo "Process: $PID is still running" >> /home/parv/waitAndRun.log
    sleep .6
done
echo "Process $PID has finished" >> /home/parv/waitAndRun.log
```

/usr/bin/waitingScript.sh

http://iamparv.blogspot.in/2013/10/unix-wait-for-running-process-not-child.html

Comment: Smart trick! One can wait like this and then launch scripts after the process is finished.

Comment: not so good, if every computer program used polling like this, it would be a very bad thing :)

Comment: I'll not be able to get the exit code of child process

Comment: neat. i can't believe there isn't a standard tool to do this anywhere... i've made a simpler shell script called `waitpid` that's basically this one-liner: `while [ -e /proc/$1 ]; do sleep 1; done`...

Comment: @anarcat Is there any way to get exit status?

Comment: @pmor i doubt that: that's typically available only to the parent.

Answer (score 7):

Either your while loop or the for loop runs in a subshell, which is why you cannot await a child of the (parent, outer) shell.

**Edit** this might happen if the while loop or for loop is actually

(a) in a `{...}` block
  (b) participating in a piper (e.g. `for....done|somepipe`)

Comment: You could check this line of thinking, nonetheless, e.g. printing $BASHPID, $$, $BASH_SUBSHELL in both locations (and at the toplevel of your script!)

Answer (score 7):

If you're running this in a container of some sort, the condition [apparently can be caused by a bug in bash that is easier to encounter in a containerized envrionment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxd/+bug/1590001).

From my reading of [the bash source](http://%20http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/) (specifically see comments around `RECYCLES_PIDS` and `CHILD_MAX` in `bash-4.2/jobs.c`), it looks like in their effort to optimize their tracking of background jobs, they leave themselves vulnerable to PID aliasing (where a new process might obscure the status of an old one); to mitigate that, they prune their background process history (apparently as mandated by POSIX?). If you should happen to want to `wait` on a pruned process, the shell can't find it in the history and assumes this to mean that it never knew about it (i.e., that it "is not a child of this shell").

Comment: I think I'm running into this issue. Do you know if it will be fixed at all?

Comment: @Clete2 it's apparently been this way for 8+ years and the [exacerbating] behavior is seemingly at least partially mandated by POSIX compliance.  I wouldn't expect it to change anytime soon.