# wait for a background PID from another background function

Tags: shell, ksh

Using ksh93 i'm attempting to wait for a background process ,run_cataloguer(), to finish, from within a separate background process ,send_mail(), using the script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

function run_cataloguer
{
    echo "In run_cataloguer()"
    sleep 2
    echo "leaving run_cataloguer()"
}
function send_mail
{
    echo "In send_mail()"
    #jobs
    wait_for_cataloguer
    sleep 1
    echo "Leaving send_mail() "
}
function wait_for_cataloguer
{
    echo "In wait_for_cataloguer() PID_CAT = $PID_CAT"
    wait $PID_CAT
    waitRet=$?
    echo "waitRet = $waitRet"
}

run_cataloguer &
PID_CAT=$!
echo "PID_CAT = $PID_CAT"

send_mail &

wait                            # Wait for all
echo "Finished main"
```

The following output is seen:

```
PID_CAT = 1265
In run_cataloguer()
In send_mail()
In wait_for_cataloguer() PID_CAT = 1265
waitRet = 127   # THIS SHOULD be 0
Leaving send_mail()
leaving run_cataloguer()
Finished main
```

The problem is 
waitRet = 127
which means the wait command can't see $PID_CAT, so it doesn't wait for run_cataloguer() to finish and
"leaving send_mail()"
is printed before
"leaving run_cataloguer()"
If I run send_mail in the foreground then waitRet = 0, which is correct.

So, it appears that you cannot wait for a background process from within a separate background process.
Also, if I uncomment the jobs command, nothing is returned , which appears to confirm the previous statement. 
If anyone has a solution ,apart form using flag files, :), it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this cannot be done. The solution I used was from Parvinder here:
[wait child process but get error: 'pid is not a child of this shell'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048628/wait-child-process-but-get-error-pid-is-not-a-child-of-this-shell)