# Background jobs in codebuild

Tags: linux, shell, background, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to run background tasks in Codebuild using the nohup command as described in the document (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-background-tasks.html)

Below is the buildspec I'm using

```
version: 0.2 
phases:   
  build:
    commands:
      - nohup sleep 30 & echo $! > pidfile 
      - wait $(cat pidfile)
```

I get an error for this as below

```
[Container] 2021/08/25 06:04:40 Running command wait $(cat pidfile)
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: line 4: wait: pid 207 is not a child of this shell

[Container] 2021/08/25 06:04:40 Command did not exit successfully wait $(cat pidfile) exit status 127
[Container] 2021/08/25 06:04:40 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
```

I do not understand why the wait command i being executed in a different shell. Is there any way how I can make this execute in the same shell or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same, sometimes `wait` doesn't work in CodeBuild.

I found [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56879673/19304238) that might explain the issue.

There can be workarounds to replace `wait`:

- poll the PID until it exists, e.g.: `while [ -e /proc/$PID ]; do sleep 1; done` ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19396161/19304238)), or you can also use `ps --pid $PID > /dev/null` or `kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null` or [some other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41613532/19304238) to determine whether the background process finished
- copy the stdout file descriptor of the command to a custom one, and read from that until it is closed:

```
exec 3< <(sleep 3 2>&1)  
...  
cat <&3  # print the output of the background process and will wait until it exits
```

A big limitation of these is that the exit code of the background process is unknown (`wait` would return with that). You have to save it somewhere if you need it.